# PHP: How do i get the values of the this JSON?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the values of teams in the Json,I gave tried the code below but it returns NULL, Any ideas?

[image]

```
<?php

$url = 'http://bristolrugby.matchdaylive.com/tools/ajax/cache.php?';
$url.= 'type=Fixture&format=json&TeamId=25&Source=sfms&module=StatsRugbyMDS&CompSeason=2015&project=bristol';


$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$fixture_array = $response;

var_dump ($fixture_array->SoticFeed->Fixtures->Fixture[0]->Teams->Team);

echo '<br/><hr>';

$fix = $fixture_array->SoticFeed->Fixtures;

 foreach($fix as $fix){

print  $fix->Fixture->Teams->Team->TmnmDisplay . "<hr>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the result of `file_get_contents($url)`? It might be that it never gets the JSON. That said, your `foreach` loop uses the same variables, and you should use `foreach(...->Fixtures->Fixture)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you got confused by the structure of the data. Your final loop is wrong, I think it should look like this:

```
$fix = $fixture_array->SoticFeed->Fixtures->Fixture;
foreach($fix as $fix_detail){
    foreach($fix_detail->Teams->Team as $team){
        print  $team->TmnmDisplay . "<hr>";
    }
}
```

This is assuming you want to display all team's names. If this is not what you intended please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

hello your Json response return array in array in array and this mean you have to loop over each  key , let me explain you more

if you

```
print_r($response["SoticFeed]")
```

You will get Array in Array , now again

```
print_r($response["SoticFeed"]["Fixtures"])
```

again You will get Array , now the last part

```
foreach($response["SoticFeed"]["Fixtures"]["Fixture"] as $key=>$value){

print_r($value)


}
```

Comment: Don't be confused, `json_decode` does not return an array unless you specify it setting the second argument to `true`. The result in this case are `stdClass` objects.

Comment: Yah Sorry for that .